# How can i prevent current clocked task from showing in modeline?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

Is there any way to disable clocked task from being shown in modeline? I tried searching for variables, but i couldn't find any that turns it off.

Comment: maybe function `timeclock-mode-line-display` and variable `timeclock-mode-line-display` could help?

Comment: I don't use the most recent version of org-mode, but the last time a similar question came up, I tracked the clock setting back to org-mode setting the `global-mode-string` (which is used by the default `mode-line-format`) and the `org-timer-mode-line-string`.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the variable `org-clock-clocked-in-display`.  The docstring reads:

```
Documentation:
When clocked in for a task, Org can display the current
task and accumulated time in the mode line and/or frame title.
Allowed values are:

both         displays in both mode line and frame title
mode-line    displays only in mode line (default)
frame-title  displays only in frame title
nil          current clock is not displayed
```